# Swift 3: How to set the special characters in Dictionary<String, Any>?

Tags: json, dictionary, swift3

I want below JSON

```
{
  "username":"abc",
  "password":"-"
}
```

I am setting the values in dictionary as following:

```
dictionary["username"] = userObject.username
dictionary["password"] = "-"
```

But when I debug the code, dictionary["password"] shows unable to read data.

I don't know how to set the hyphen(-) in dictionary value.
I tried "\"-\"". It saves the value as "-" but I need just -.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write this code:

```
var Dict =  ["username":"abc", "password":"-"]

for key in Dict.keys
{
    let data = Dict[key]?.data(using: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)
    Dict[key] = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
print(Dict)
```